# Google Cloud Load Balancing Service expansion

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm creating a internal load balancing with single backend service, where this backend service holds single instance group with four instances running our application (cluster). 
I'm scaling our cluster to 6 nodes (by adding additional 2 instances). Now, the idea is to update the load balancing setup to include 2 additional instances. 
What will be the best and correct way to do it? Seems like i can't just add these 2 new instances to existing backend service.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i forgot to update the tags for the newly added instances. Once its done, the new instances can be added to existing backend service